# How to apply "Envelope Muliply" in Deform in Export

Tags: animation, armature, export

Title. I have a bugged shoulder in animation of a mesh that I have imported into UE4. I went back into blender to select the bone and I went to bone properties and checked "Deform" which was ticked. If I tick it off, it will fix the bone in animation. If I tick the "Envelope Multiply"-box, it will also fix it in animation.

When I export it however, it returns back to normal. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Any chance there's anything in the export settings that controls this as well?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Not that I can see?
https://i.gyazo.com/8e438603cffd3a477cc7c326612bb538.png

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. I don't export .fbx with bones very often. Maybe play around with the armature settings - uncheck "add leaf bones" or check "only deform bones", or both. Play around, that's the best I, personally, can do. Maybe someone with more experience exporting .fbx with armatures will come along.

Comment: Alright so I was able to fix it. Apparently there was added vertex weight to the shoulder without me knowing. Envelope Multiply only displayed what it looked like without that weight. So I went into the Weight Painter and added a subtract brush and brushed over the shoulder :)